# Q: How to Group on Converted Datecolumns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm Using TSQL on Microsoft SQL Server 2016

I want to create an SQL that give me the count of pics by Employee, Grouped by Year and Month (last 36 Months)

So this is what I tried first:

```
  select 
    count(emp) AS NumberOfPics,
    emp AS employee,
    LEFT(picdatum,4) AS YearPic,
    (Select Top 36 left(dbo.f376.picdatum,6))
FROM Storage
GROUP BY emp, LEFT(picdatum,4),  LEFT(picdatum,6)
```

it worked fine [Result of my SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zra6v.jpg)

But the result of the dates are not that good.

So i made a second one.

```
  select top 10
        CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),picdatum)),
    DATEPART(YYYY,CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),picdatum))) AS YearPic,
    DATEPART(MM, CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),picdatum))) AS MonthPic,
    DATEPART(WW, CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),picdatum))) AS WeekPic
  from storage
```

The Datepard and result is looking much more better.

But here comes the problem, i need your Help for:

if i try to combine the it with:

```
  select  count(emp) AS NumberOfPics,
         emp AS Employee,
        CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),picdatum)),
    DATEPART(YYYY,CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),picdatum))) AS YearPic,
    DATEPART(MM, CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),picdatum))) AS MonthPic,
    DATEPART(WW, CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),picdatum))) AS WeekPic
from storage
GROUP BY emp, YearPic,  MonthPic
```

It probably won´t work, even if i use the left part again, it comes to:

The storage.picdatum column is invalid in the selection list because it is not included in an aggregate function and not in the GROUP BY clause.

So how to use the Datepart function to Group AND how to solve that aggregate problem on this specific sql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias does not work in group by clause - you need to replace those with actual

```
    select   count(emp) AS NumberOfPics,
             emp AS Employee,
             DATEPART(YYYY,CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),picdatum))) AS YearPic,
             DATEPART(MM, CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),picdatum))) AS MonthPic,
             DATEPART(WW, CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),picdatum))) AS WeekPic
    from storage
    GROUP BY emp, DATEPART(YYYY,CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),picdatum))),  DATEPART(MM, CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),picdatum))),DATEPART(WW, CONVERT 
(datetime,convert(char(8),picdatum)))
```

Comment: Thats is. Thank you !
I will accept this answer in a few minutes.